# no more optimization for mysql table?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

i think i've optimized what i could for the following tables structure:

```
   CREATE TABLE `sal_forwarding` (
  `sid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `f_shop` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `f_offer` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  `f_affiliateId` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  
  `forwardDate` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`),
  KEY `f_partner` (`f_partner`,`forwardDate`),
  KEY `forwardDate` (`forwardDate`,`cid`),
  KEY `forwardDate_2` (`forwardDate`,`f_shop`),
  KEY `forwardDate_3` (`forwardDate`,`f_shop`,`f_partner`),
  KEY `forwardDate_4` (`forwardDate`,`f_partner`,`cid`),
  KEY `forwardDate_5` (`forwardDate`,`f_affiliateId`),
  KEY `forwardDate_6` (`forwardDate`,`f_shop`,`sid`),
  KEY `forwardDate_7` (`forwardDate`,`f_shop`,`cid`),
  KEY `forwardDate_8` (`forwardDate`,`f_affiliateId`,`cid`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=10946560 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This is the explain Statement:

```
id  select_type  table           type   possible_keys                                                                                                   key             key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE       sal_forwarding  range  forwardDate,forwardDate_2,forwardDate_3,forwardDate_4,forwardDate_5,forwardDate_6,forwardDate_7,forwardDate_8   forwardDate_7   3       (NULL)  1221784 Using where; Using index; Using filesort
```

The following Query needs 23 seconds for reading 2300 rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(sid),f_shop, COUNT(DISTINCT(cid)) 
FROM sal_forwarding  
WHERE forwardDate BETWEEN "2011-01-01" AND "2011-11-01" 
GROUP BY f_shop
```

What can i do to improve the performance?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

slight modification to what you had... use count(*) instead of an actual field.  for the DISTINCT, you don't need () around it.  It may be getting confused about all the indexes you have.  Remove all other indexes on forwardDate with exception to having one based on (forwardDate, f_shop, cid ) (your current key7 index)

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(*),
      f_shop, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT cid ) 
   FROM 
      sal_forwarding  
   WHERE 
      forwardDate BETWEEN "2011-01-01" AND "2011-11-01" 
   GROUP BY 
      f_shop
```

Then, for grins, and since nothing else appears to be working for you, try putting in a pre-subquery on the records, then sum from that, so it's not relying on any other index pages based on your near 11 million records (implied per Auto-increment value)...

```
SELECT 
      f_shop, 
      sum( PreQuery.Presum) totalCnt,
      COUNT(*) dist_cid 
   FROM 
      ( select f_shop, cid, count(*) presum
           from sal_forwarding
           WHERE forwardDate BETWEEN "2011-01-01" AND "2011-11-01"
           group by f_shop, cid ) PreQuery
   GROUP BY 
      f_shop
```

Since the inner pre-query is doing a simple count of records and grouping by F_Shop and C_ID (optimizable by the index), you will now have your distinct already rolled-up via a simple count... then do a SUM() of the inner count's "presum" column.  Again, just another option to try and turn the tables, hope it works for you.

Comment: hello, the query updates doesn't improve the performance and the other inidces are in use by other queries, thats why i need so much indices.

Comment: @user954740, added additional query option for you to try.

Comment: hello, thanks for your help but the other query looks very comlicated und needs more then a minute. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `(forwardDate, f_shop, cid)` is good for this query. Not any better than a simple `(forwardDate)` index, because of the range condition on the `forwardDate` column.

You may try a `(f_shop, cid, forwardDate)` index.

Comment: hello, this is my big problem. I've never ready any good documentation about the correct using of an index. I don't know which order is the best and why. I'll try your tip.

Comment: The problem is that the `(forwardDate, f_shop, cid)` would be the best index for this query, but MySQL can't use it because of the range condition on the first part of the index. if you had a `forwardDate = '2011-01-01'`, instead of the `BETWEEN ...`, it would be used.

Comment: the query doesn't use the new index just the existing, it tells me it is the better index.